# YAML/ANSIBLE -> save variable key and value to new variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I'm working on a small ansible project for myself.

I have a `main.yml` in the defaults folder of my role.

Structure:

```
master-folder
 `- roles
     `- some_role
         |- tasks
         |   `- main.yml
         `- defaults
             `- main.yml
```

Now...
In my `some_variables.yml` I have a dictionary with 2 vars.

```
parent_var:
  child_var: bob
  child_two_var: bobby
```

in my main.yml **task** I want to get the **key and value** so (`child_var: bob`) and write it to another file.

What I need help with, is with getting the key and value from the `main.yml` in the defaults folder.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable defined in the `defaults/*.yml` is accessible from any task of the role with `{{tree.to.variable}}`.

So in your case, you can simply access the `{{parent_var}}`.

If you want to loop over keys and values, you can use the [`with_dict` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes).

```
- lineinfile:
    line: "Value for '{{ item.key }}' is '{{ item.value }}'"
    dest: /tmp/test/file1
  with_dict: "{{ parent_var }}"
```

If you need to loop in a template, there is the `{% for %}` in jinja2.

```
- copy:
    dest: /tmp/test/file
    content: |
      {% for k,v in parent_var.iteritems() %}
      Value for '{{ k }}' is '{{ v }}'
      {% endfor %}
```